# What is the meaning of following function parameter signature onChanged: ((Int?) -> Unit)? = null?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have a function with several parameters. One of these paramters is

```
private fun mySpecialFunction(
    variable1: Int,
    onChanged: ((Int?) -> Unit)? = null
)
```

Later in the function it is invoked like:

```
onChanged?.invoke(2)
```

And on the upper calling site, it is called like:

```
mySpecialFunction(
    variable1 = 1, 
    onChanged = {
        // do something with the number invoked above
    }
)
```

How is this usage of onChange called in Kotlin?

Comment: Read the following documentation: [high-order functions and lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html), [invoking a function type instance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance), [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments), [nullable types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types), and [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls). That should explain everything in the code you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onChanged` is a nullable [higher-order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html) function. The `?` in "((Int?) -> Unit)`?`" means that the value of `onChanged` can be null. Also, it has been assigned the default value `null` which means that if you don't pass a value for this parameter, it will be null.

The usual syntax for a higher order function is `(Args) -> ReturnType`. In your case, `onChanged` takes an nullable Int (`Int?`) as an argument and does not return anything i.e. returns `Unit`.

`onChanged?.invoke(2)` means that if `onChanged` is not null, invoke it and pass `2` as the argument.

```kotlin
mySpecialFunction(
    variable1 = 1, 
    onChanged = {
        // This section will get executed when the onChanged function is invoked. Here the passed `Int?` will be available as `it`
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
private fun mySpecialFunction(
    variable1: Int,
    // define nullable higher-order function with default parameter `null`
    onChanged: ((Int?) -> Unit)? = null
)

// nullsafe call && lamda invoke
onChanged?.invoke(2)

mySpecialFunction(
    variable1 = 1, 
    // define onChange lambda
    onChanged = {
    }
)

// equal to this
interface ChangeCallback {
    fun onChange(int: Int?)
}

fun mySpecialFunction(
    variable1: Int,
    onChange: ChangeCallback? = null
)
```